# Set up OpenCV library in intellij idea

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, intellij-idea, ocr

Good afternoon, Iḿ trying to use opencv in java but Iḿ getting errors when placing the driver in intellij.
I have already installed opencv and added the dependencies to my project. Iḿ using ubuntu version 22.04.

The code:

```
package ImageToText;

import org.opencv.core.Core;

public class ImageToText {

    static {System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Core.VERSION);
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java470 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at ImageToText.ImageToText.<clinit>(ImageToText.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQF9P.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWNSD.png)

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not an images.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The images were about the dependencies